# NSInvalidArgumentException....why?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have this code, where self.currentSet.imagesPrefix is a NSString and also [attributeDict objectForKey@"imagesPrefix"] is a NSSTring

```
self.currentSet.imagesPrefix=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"imagesPrefix"];
```

but in console I have this problem:

```
2011-11-15 16:04:08.850 MyApp[8579:707] -[__NSCFString setImagesPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x168600
2011-11-15 16:04:08.857 MyApp[8579:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setImagesPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x168600'
```

Comment: `self.currentSet`, what is it? I guess it may not be NSString object, but it is. It looks like `currentSet` was overreleased and pointer points to wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't synthesized your imagesPrefix to generate the setImagesPrefix method.

Comment: Perhaps you need to declare as NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `self.currentSet` is not the object you think it is. Instead of chaining the properties, pull it apart into separate stages so you can debug:

```
id firstpart = self.currentSet;
NSLog(@"%@", firstpart);
```

This will reveal what `self.currentSet` really is. Prepare for a surprise. Then the real debugging can begin, because you'll have to figure out *why* it isn't what you think it is.